# MEF composition import issue when using specific interface

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I work with MEF for a long time and once in a while it just drives me crazy. Have NO idea what it needs.

I have 2 files that we interested in:

1. My EXE with 2 classes:

JobFactory : IJobFactory and SaferWatchProcessor : IJob

2. Quartz.net DLL which have those interfaces definitions

Creating container:

```
var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(
                new DirectoryCatalog(".", "*.dll"),
                new DirectoryCatalog(".", "*.exe"));

            Bootstrapper.CompositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog, true);
```

catalog now have JobFactory but NO SaferWatchProcessor. Why?

[image]

Here is classes:

```
[Export(typeof(IJob))]
public class SaferWatchProcessor : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SaferWatchProcessor.Execute");
    }
}
```

SaferWatchProcessor has nothing there, just one method. Has Export attribute.

```
[Export(typeof(IJobFactory))]
    public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        [ImportMany(typeof(IJob))]
        public List<IJob> Jobs { get; private set; }

        public virtual IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            IJobDetail jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
            Type jobType = jobDetail.JobType;
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory - creating job instance");
                return this.Jobs.First();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var se = new SchedulerException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Problem instantiating class '{0}'", jobDetail.JobType.FullName), e);
                throw se;
            }
        }

        public virtual void ReturnJob(IJob job)
        {
        }
    }
```

JobFactory has ImportMany (which doesn't fail, but has 0 items)

I tried to set it as single Import and was getting following error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition Warning: 1 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory' has been rejected. The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

    1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
        ContractName    Quartz.IJob
        RequiredTypeIdentity    Quartz.IJob

    Resulting in: Cannot set import 'IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory.Jobs (ContractName="Quartz.IJob")' on part 'IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory'.
    Element: IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory.Jobs (ContractName="Quartz.IJob") -->  IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory -->  DirectoryCatalog (Path=".")

    A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in IDATT.WindowsService.exe
```

Nothing seems to be wrong, but why it doesn't want to import IJob?

EDIT:

I removed all IJob definitions and use plain Export/Import and added debugging for MEF. Still problem and here is error:

```
[Part] IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory from: DirectoryCatalog (Path="C:\CodeWorkspace\IdattLC\ClientServerCode\IDATT.WindowsService\bin\Debug\")
  [Primary Rejection]
  [Export] IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory (ContractName="Quartz.Spi.IJobFactory")
  [Import] IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory.SaferWatchProcessor (ContractName="IDATT.WindowsService.Jobs.SaferWatchProcessor")
    [Exception] System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException: No exports were found that match the constraint: 
    ContractName    IDATT.WindowsService.Jobs.SaferWatchProcessor
    RequiredTypeIdentity    IDATT.WindowsService.Jobs.SaferWatchProcessor
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition)
   at Microsoft.ComponentModel.Composition.Diagnostics.CompositionInfo.AnalyzeImportDefinition(ExportProvider host, IEnumerable`1 availableParts, ImportDefinition id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out hard way. I thought it will be useful to post my findings.

What happened is that I installed MEF 2 from NuGet, new lightweight MEF for 4.5 and Windows store.

All my existing libraries was built with regular old MEF
`using System.ComponentModel.Composition` and for this problematic import ReSharper suggested couple namespaces and I used `import using System.Composition` for Export attribute

not sure what good in MEF 2, but it's not going to work with existing libraries/exports against regular MEF so be careful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick check list:

- Ensure that assembly with `SaferWatchProcessor` type is physically copied to catalog folder
- Ensure that corresponding assemblies are fresh and have correct time stamps in catalog folder
- Ensure that `SaferWatchProcessor` type really exports `Quartz.IJob`. It is a common mistake when people are trying to export an empty interface created by Visual Studio instead of referencing the real one

Comment: ogggre, thanks for suggestion. I'm really lost here. I took interface off class completely and use plain Import/Export attributes. IDATT.WindowsService.Jobs.SaferWatchProcessor is in the same assembly(.EXE) as IDATT.WindowsService.JobFactory but it is not "visible" to parts composer..